# Best strategy for Object localisation without using pretrained model and weights.?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to train a model from scratch without using any pre-trained model and weights with 20k image dataset and 4 coordinates of the object.Can you suggest me the best approach to work on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you try any of the existing architectures - YOLO, SSD, Faster-RCNN to name a few (or their next-gens) and see what is the performance?
Of course, if you know in advance the properties of the objects in your data set this can be useful - e.g. for smaller objects, Faster-RCNN would probably yield better performance that SSD and YOLO.
Each one of them has available open source implementations in all leading DNN frameworks.